# Error: [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$location/nobase at Error (native)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I try to Hide # in Url of Angular js, am getting this error. Please Help out. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is from angular's documentation:

> If you configure `$location` to use `html5Mode` (`history.pushState`), you need to specify the base URL for the application with a `<base href="">` tag or configure `$locationProvider` to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with `requireBase:false` to `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

More info at angular's [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

Answer (score 1):

`<head>
  <base href="/"> 
   ..... 
</head>`

//add this in your main.html
source:https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8866